# django custom form validation error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

when i am saving the modelform with blank image field, then it shows error, And this error is due to the custom form validation of image field in the modelform. And also the if statement is not working in custom form validation method.

```
" 'unicode' object has no attribute '_size' ".
```

models.py

```
class ImageUpload(models.Model):
    image  = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
    name = models.CharField(max_length='128')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'image_upload'
```

formy.py

```
 class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
     model = ImageUpload

    def clean_image(self):
       image = self.cleaned_data.get('image',None)
       if image: # this is not working, if image field is blank
          if image._size:
                if image:
                    if image._size > 1*1024*1024:
                        raise ValidationError("Image file too large ( > 4mb )")
                    return image
                else:
                    raise ValidationError("Couldn't read uploaded image")
            else:
                raise ValidationError("image format should be .png %s"%(image_format))
```

views.py

```
def add_image(request):
    response_data = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        context = {
                'form':form
                   }
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            response_data['status'] = 'true'
            response_data['message'] = 'successfully added'
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type='application/javascript')
        else:
            response_data['message'] = form.errors
        #return HttpResponse(response_data)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type='application/javascript')
    else:
        form = ImageUploadForm()
        context = {
                'form':form
                   }
        return render(request,'users/add_image.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on the form

```
image = self.cleaned_data.get('image',None)
```

you should get the image like

```
if 'image' in request.FILES:
    image = request.FILES['image']
```